# Default Input value for datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a fairly simple date time picker in angular, similar to docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2017-06-01T08:30">
```

This works fine if I want a fixed hardcoded date. But I want the default value to be a variable, so i can use current date and time.
I tried using value="someVar" where someVar = "2017-06-01T08:30", but the value is not read. So it looks like hardcoded date is working, stored date is not.
Suggestions? Thanks!

edit: I can't share the ts code, but I have this for the date var

export class someComp {
someVar: string = "2017-06-01T08:30"

etc...

}

Comment: Can you please share the Typescript code of the component?

Comment: I never used angular so I might say something completely wrong, but shouldn't there be some framework specific way of using variables like `value={{someVar}}` or `ng-model="someVar"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to send the 'someVar' to input, use `[value]="someVar"`.

If you want to have 'someVar' potentially changable by some logic later (in ts) use `value="{{someVar}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize a component property with a valid date string and then use interpolation to initialize the `datetime-local` field

e.g.:

```
export class someComp { 
   ...
   someVar: string = "";
   ...
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.someVar = new Date().toISOString(); // current time in UTC
   }
```

then in the template

```
...
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{someVar}}">
...
```